# How to eliminate invalid quadrilateral matches from homography, RANSAC?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, sift, homography, ransac

This question was already asked 7 years ago, but no valid answers that I can apply.
This is my exact case:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/filtering-ransac-estimated-homographies/9301#9301
I am using ASIFT algorithm to match two images using SIFT, to eliminate outliers I am using findHomography, RANSAC. I'm getting satisfactory results if the images are under less than 30 degree angle variance.
How can I eliminate invalid quadrilaterals that I get when I perform perspectiveTransform with the template image and homography Matrix.
Currently I'm performing an area check and minimum angle check, that minimum angle in the quadrilateral should be greater than 60 degrees, this fails for certain cases obviously, I'm rejecting some valid matches where the minimum angle can be less than 60d and still form a good quadrilateral.

Comment: Is it sufficient to check that it is convex?

Comment: @alkasm I checked the area, it should atleast be some percentage of the test image, and I did a convex check, also checking for intersecting quadrilateral and eliminating them. This covered most of my cases.                                                               https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonconvex.html

Comment: Any cases that it doesn't cover?